# Allocating memory for a struct in SPARC Assembly

Tags: assembly, sparc

I'm trying to figure out how to allocate memory for a struct in SPARC assembly.

Here's the C version of my code that I'm using (which works and compiles fine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct tester test;
    ....other code inbetween

    testfn(&test);
    testfn2(&test);
}
```

Now in assembly I figure I have to call a function like this...

```
mov struct tester, %o0    ! Move struct tester into %o0

call sizeof               ! Get size of struct tester
nop

set %o0, %l1              ! Store size
nop

mov 1, %o0                ! Prepare for calloc call
mov %l1, %o1              ! Prepare for calloc call

call calloc, 2
nop

mov %o0, %l2              ! The pointer returned to the allocated space

mov %l2, %o0

call testfn
nop

mov %l2, %o0

call testfn2
nop
```

The main part I'm stuck on right now is how to pass that initial struct tester test into assembly. Do I define it somewhere or how does it work?

And just in case, my struct tester looks something like this...

```
#define SIZE 100

struct tester2 {
   char abcd[SIZE];
   char efgh[SIZE];
};

struct tester {
   struct tester2 *somePTR;
   int             an_Int;
};
```

Comment: `sizeof` isn't a function, it's a compile-time operator

Comment: So does that mean I have to calculate the size of my struct by hand more or less? I figure the size would be then..

    4 for the an_Int,
    4 for the somePTR,
    200 for the struct tester2

Right? *Edit* I lied, did a printf in c and it returned 8 :) Guess I need to read a bit more about how space is allocated :)

Comment: It depends on what assembler you're using - there may be some way to keep the asm version of the struct in sync with the C version - failing that then yes, you'll need to take care of it "manually". Note that you don't need to call calloc though - - you can just allocate the struct statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do. In the C code, it looks like you are allocating space for the structure on the stack.

```
struct tester test;
```

In the assembly code, though it contains some odd statements, it looks like you are want to use the size of a structure in a call to calloc to allocate space.

```
mov 1, %o0                ! Prepare for calloc call
mov %l1, %o1              ! Prepare for calloc call

call calloc, 2
```

So, decide what you want to do and either 1) allocate memory for a local variable on the stack by using the save instruction to decrement %sp or 2) just call calloc().

Comment: Hey Torgny,

Thanks for the reply, I wanted to add my own answer because I figured it out but I have an 8 hour limit, here's my answer I posted. If you could tell me if my line of thinking is correct I'd appreciate it :)

I'm calling a C function to put stuff into the struct, I don't need to worry about how to process it, I just need to allocate enough space on the STACK for everything to fit when it gets called by the other C functions.

Also, my question might have been confusing in that testfn and testfn2 were other C modules that I had written. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Well, to allocate space for just one tester structure, you should do save %sp, -104, %sp at the start of your function and you will have your structure at %fp-8.